# stl: эстетические предпочтения для заполнения map

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, map, контейнеры

**Стоит задача:**

есть контейнер `std::map<int, int>`

необходимо добавить в контейнер элемент, если такого элемента в контейнере нет или увеличить значение `second`, если элемент в контейнере присутствует

Интересно ваше мнение, какой подход лучше (как я понимаю по функциональности и скорости предложенные варианты идентичные на 100%, так что остается только эстетическая составляющая, но я могу и ошибаться).

**Решения:**

**вариант 1:**

```
std::map<int, int>::iterator it = m_container.find(key);

if (it != m_container.end())
    it->second += value;
else
    m_container.insert(std::pair<int, int>(key, value));
```

**вариант 2:**

```
auto res = m_container.insert(std::pair<int, int>(key, value));

if ((res.second == false) && (res.second != m_container.end())
    res.first->second += value;
```

ну или, если считать, что никаких косяков не должно произойти, то просто

```
auto res = m_container.insert(std::pair<int, int>(key, value));

if (res.second == false)
    res.first->second += value;
```

**P.S.**

полностью написал все эти `iterator`, потому, что не уверен, что использование `auto` не решит вставить константный итератор (для `std::map::find`)

**P.P.S.**

а может это все как-то более компактно, логически и правильно делается в c++1x?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Мне кажется, что так короче и проще всего...

```
m_container[key]+=value;
```

Если, конечно, устраивает нулевое начальное значение, т.е. после вставки первого элемента значение будет равно `value`.

Comment: нет, нулевое значение не устраивает - т.е. если элемент не добавлялся, то его как бы и нет, или что-то не так я понял?

Comment: @Zhihar Если элемента не было, то `m_container[key]+=value;` сначала вставит ноль, а потом прибавит нему 1.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, а какие могут быть из-за этого косяки? только если я складываю не числа, а например буквы и будет тогда вместо `a + b + c = abc` `0abc`? В общем не совсем корректный результат, а для чисел вроде никаких проблем не должно возникнуть?

Comment: @Zhihar, Вы складываете `int`ы, ответ Вам для `int`ов. Если интересует решение для других типов, приведите эти типы. Тип «буквы» в C++ отсутствует.

Comment: @ixSci, да мне int и double хватит за глаза :) просто как раз стало интересно как этот 0 может негативно влиять

Comment: Я имел в виду - представим, что, внося значения 10, 20 и 30, вам нужно получить 110, 130 и 160 соответственно - типа, при создании пустой записи в ней сразу должно находиться значение 100...

Comment: @Zhihar Нет, для строк будет добавляться пустая строка. Так что никаких проблем не будет. В общем случае добавляется `тип()`, что для чисел соответствует `0`, для строк - `""`.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

std::map<int, int> m;

void inc(int key, int value)
{
    m[key] += value;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    inc(1, 1);
    inc(1, 3);

    inc(2, 2);
    inc(2, 5);

    std::cout << m[1] << " " << m[2];

    return 0;
}
```

Результат: 4 7